# How to output multiple records from Transformer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Given: DSL topology with `KStream::transform`. As part of `Transformer::transform` execution multiple messages are generated from the input one (`KeyValue<String, Message>`).

I probably can return `KeyValue<String, List<Message>>` object from the `Transformer::transform` and apply `flatMapValues` as the next processor in the topology to flat the list. However I'm wondering is it possible to use `ProcessorContext::forward` for the same goal, i.e

```
public KeyValue<String, Message> transform(String key, Message message) {
        Iterable<Message> messages = generateMultipleFromOne(message);
        messages.forEach(m->context.forward(key, m));

        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [javadoc of Transformer.transform(K key, V value)](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Transformer.html#transform-K-V-):

> If more than one output record should be forwarded downstream,
> `ProcessorContext.forward(Object, Object)` and
> `ProcessorContext.forward(Object, Object, To)` can be used.
>
> Note that returning a new KeyValue is merely for convenience. The same can be achieved by using `ProcessorContext.forward(Object, Object)` and returning null.